# Date Criteria in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use MS-Access to fiter my dates. Example--> from yesterday till today
i am using the formula in criteria as  below:

> =Val(Year(Date()-1))*10000+Val(Month(Date()-1))*100+Val(Day(Date()-1))--this is for yesterdays date

its not working as its says Please chk the code and recompile. SOme how same formulaworks in another version(older version) of MS access.

Can you please help with this? is there any setting/Plugin we need to have?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is far easier to use `DateAdd` to get dates relative to another date:

```
=DateAdd("d",-1,Date())
```

Will give you yesterday's date:

[image]

Regards,

Comment: DateAdd("d",-1,Date()) does not work as it gives error tat Visual basic module contains syntax error.